# HtmlUnit get div element by class inside a DomElement?

Tags: java, htmlunit

Hello I am using [HtmlUnit library](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) and I need to get some href attribute from an `a` tag, inside some div:

```
<div class="threadpostedin td alt">
    <p>Forum:<br>
    <a href="programming/website-development/"
    title="Website Development">Website
    Development</a></p>
</div>
```

This div is located inside a `<li>` which is located inside a `<ol>`

to get the `ol` I did this:

```
HtmlOrderedList l = (HtmlOrderedList) this.page.getElementById("searchbits");
```

The html:

```
<ol class="searchbits" id="searchbits" start="1">
```

Now from the div I posted, I need to get the href `"programming/website-development/"`, but I am not sure how to do this. Yes the div has a class name, but if I do

```
for (DomElement ele : l.getChildElements()) {
    System.out.println(ele.getByXPath("//div[@class='threadpostedin td alt']").size());
    break;
}
```

it will print 15, because overall there are 15 lists in the `ol`, in each list there is one div with class `threadpostedin td alt`. What I need to do, is the the exact div with class `threadpostedin td alt` in the `DomElement` I got from the iteration, and not get the list of all divs with that class.

Is there a way to do this with HtmlUnit?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have more links than one to make it more detailed.

```
    HtmlElement element = page.getByXPath("//div[@class='threadpostedin td alt']").get(0);
    DomNodeList<DomNode> nodes = element.querySelectorAll("a");
    for(DomNode a : nodes) {

        if(a.getAttributes().getNamedItem("href") !=null) {

            String href = page.getFullyQualifiedUrl(a.getAttributes().getNamedItem("href").getNodeValue()).toString().toLowerCase();
            String baseUrl = page.getBaseURL().toString();      

    }
}
```